# How to add class only to top level ul in main menu

Tags: theming, navigation

I am new to drupal theming.I want to add class only to top level ul in main menu.Using theme_menu__tree_main_menu() affect all the ul tag.I found this for adding class only to top level..https://www.drupal.org/node/988694
function THEMENAME_menu_tree__menu_top_menu($variables) {
 return '' . $variables['tree'] . '';
}
But it didn't work.Doesn't adding any class.Am I missing something?Please Suggest Me!!Thank

Answer (score 0):

That example is missing some code.  Those two empty strings should not be empty.

There is a link on that page just above the code example to api documentation of theme_menu_tree() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7.x

On the api documentation page you can see it done correctly:

```
return '<ul class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
```

Comment: I updated that documentation page on the Drupal site for future viewers.

Comment: Thank!!.I already try "<ul class='myclass'>" in theme_menu_tree__menu_top_menu() but still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know in fact that your function is being called?  Could be a issue with function name - if you are calling this from your theme, the function name should start with 'YOUR_THEME_NAME_menu_tree...' and not 'theme_menu_tree...'  Did you Clear All Caches (under Admin->Config->Performance)?

Comment: Thank!!Yes I clear all the cache.My theme name is "abc" so I called the function abc_menu_tree__menu_top_menu(&$variables).Does this function require to override working only for main menu.

Comment: Your function should only override the one menu named 'menu_top_menu'  and not any other menus.

Comment: Thank!!How can I override the function theme_menu_tree__menu_top_menu() work for main menu

Comment: You need another function for that menu - using the name of your main menu.  So if the main menu is named "menu_main_menu" and your theme is "abc" then the function name would be  "abc_menu_tree__menu_main_menu()"

Comment: Thank!!My menu name is main_menu so write this functions in template.php file am I right.`function abc_menu_tree__main_menu(&$variables){
    return '<ul class="menu">'.$variables['tree'].'</ul>';
}
function abc_menu_tree__menu_top_menu(&$variables){
 return '<ul class="menu myclass">'.$variables['tree'].'</ul>';
}`

Comment: I get the menu name from `menu_get_names()`function.

Comment: With this function you need to put "menu" in front of the menu name, so it should be "abc_menu_tree__menu_main_menu()"

Comment: Thank!! I try but still doesn't add any class.When I use `abc_menu_tree__menu_main_menu()`it doesn't add any class.But when I try`abc_menu_tree__main_menu()` it add class but affecting all the ul element.

Comment: Sorry about previous "menu" comment, was thinking of something else.  I realize your question now is actually 2 issues, the first was the theme call with the empty strings, so at least that part is working for you.  The answer for the second part of only affecting the top ul element, for the submenus you will need to use hook_menu_link() see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7.x